# How to implement a double queue structure in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow to implement a Neutral Network, and want to achieve such architecture: there are 2 queues, namely Q1 and Q2. Q1 is initialised with some file names, and Q2 will be filled with examples later.

Every time the session runs a step, a file name is popped from Q1, and enters a processing part. In the processing part, data is read from the file, and **generated some, say 32, different examples from the data**. Then, the generated 32 examples will be enqueued into Q2. If Q2 reached some limit, it dequeues a batch of examples.

In particular, I will generated nearly 1M examples every time read from a file, so **such process must run in the background and avoid block the main thread**, and enqueueing into Q2 must be asynchronously.

I failed to find a solution. I have tried something like the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

q1 = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=32, dtypes=tf.int32)
init_op = q1.enqueue_many(([0, 1, 2],))

q2 = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=64, dtypes=tf.int32)

r = q1.dequeue()

# mimic generating examples from data read from the file
for i in range(10):
    enq_op = q2.enqueue(r * 10 + i)

s = q2.dequeue()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

sess.run(init_op)

# don't know what to do

sess.close()
```

Could anyone help!

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that you are confusing graph construction and execution. Your `for i in range(10)` loop creates a bunch of enqueue ops, it won't actually add `r*10+i` to your queue.

I recommend going through the queue tutorial first to understand the basic concepts -- https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html .  Also [this](http://yaroslavvb.blogspot.com/2016/05/queues-in-tensorflow.html)

Comment: Hi! Thanks to your reply, and I DO have realised that I misunderstood those two concepts. Now I believe I am clear about them, and have made some attempts, but still fails. Could you have a look at my new question and give my some help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797751/running-queue-in-background-in-tensorflow-causes-strange-exceptions