# Running queue in background in Tensorflow causes strange exceptions

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am implementing such graph in Tensorflow: there is a queue Q, to which a background thread is enqueueing tensors. In the main thread, I sequentially dequeue elements from Q.

My code can be simplified as following:

```py
import time
import threading
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

q = tf.FIFOQueue(32, dtypes=tf.int32)

def loop(g):
    with g.as_default():
        enqueue_op = q.enqueue(1, name="example_enqueue")

        for i in range(20):
            if coord.should_stop():
                return

            try:
                sess.run(enqueue_op)
            except tf.errors.CancelledError:
                print("enqueue canncelled")

threads = [
    threading.Thread(target=loop, args=(tf.get_default_graph(),))
]

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

for t in threads: t.start()

# If I sleep 1 seconds, it will be fine!
# time.sleep(1)

print(sess.run(q.dequeue()))

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)

sess.close()
```

I commented, if I sleep 1 second before running dequeue operation, things will be fine. However, if run immediately, following exception will be raised:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 715, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 697, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors.py", line 450, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: FetchOutputs node fifo_queue_Dequeue:0: not found
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/hanxu/Downloads/BrainSeg/playgrounds/7.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(sess.run(q.dequeue()))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 636, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 708, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 728, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: FetchOutputs node fifo_queue_Dequeue:0: not found
HanXus-MacBook-Pro:BrainSeg hanxu$ python3 -m playgrounds.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 715, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 697, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors.py", line 450, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: FetchOutputs node fifo_queue_Dequeue:0: not found
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/hanxu/Downloads/BrainSeg/playgrounds/7.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(sess.run(q.dequeue()))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 636, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 708, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 728, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: FetchOutputs node fifo_queue_Dequeue:0: not found
```

Could anyone help? Thanks very much!!

### Update

I am using Tensorflow 9.0rc0.

My real situation is a little more complicated. The enqueued tensor is in fact different at each time, say

```py
def loop(g):
    with g.as_default():
        for i in range(20):
            if coord.should_stop():
                return

            # Look here!
            enqueue_op = q.enqueue(i, name="example_enqueue")

            try:
                sess.run(enqueue_op)
            except tf.errors.CancelledError:
                print("enqueue canncelled")
```

So it is not trivial to move the enqueue operation to main thread:( and I don't know how. Please help:)

Answer (score 2):

This was [an issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2425) with old (pre-0.9) versions of TensorFlow, which was [fixed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/acac487ac4ebaa6edb3e3f866d41cbd12546a107) in version 0.9. The issue is that adding nodes to the graph (i.e. in your calls to `q.dequeue()` and `q.enqueue()`) was not thread-safe when other threads (i.e. your `loop()` thread) were using the graph.

There are two issues you'd need to fix to avoid the race condition (in pre-0.9 versions):

1. Don't call `q.enqueue()` in the `loop()` thread. Instead create it in the main thread. For example:

   ```
   q = tf.FIFOQueue(32, dtypes=tf.int32)
   enqueue_op = q.enqueue(1, name="example_enqueue")

   def loop(g):
       for i in range(20):
           if coord.should_stop():
               return
           try:
               sess.run(enqueue_op)
           except tf.errors.CancelledError:
               print("enqueue canncelled")
   ```
2. Move the call to `q.dequeue()` (which adds a node to the graph) before where you start the `loop()` thread:

   ```
   dequeued_t = q.dequeue()

   for t in threads: t.start()

   print(sess.run(deqeueued_t))
   ```

Comment: Isn't it still not thread-safe for concurrent writes? `q.dequeue()` and `q.enqueue` run in parallel and both modify graph

Comment: Ah good point, it's more broken than I thought. Updated the answer to suggest both fixes.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! In fact I am using 9.0rc0. After imply your 2 suggestion, the problem did go away! However, in my real situation, it seems that your first modification can not be applied by me. Please refer to my update to the question:)

Comment: For your updated question, you could create a single enqueue op that takes a `tf.placeholder()` as input and feed different values. Does that make sense?